# how to process filenames correct with shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to eval the latest filename inside my latest folder with some shell script. 
So im getting the latest folder name and the latest filename inside it:

```
latest_folder=$(ls -td */ | head -n 1)
echo $latest_folder
cd $latest_folder
latest_file="$(ls -t *$str | head -n 1)"
echo $latest_file
```

folder structure:

```
base_folder
    |
    |---000
    |     |---123.*
    |     |---124.*
    |     |---...
    |     |---999.*
    |
    |---001
    |     |---997.*
    |     |---998.*
    |     |---999.*
```

Where 001 is the latest folder. If the latest file inside this folder equals 999.* i need to create a new folder 002.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is not far off. I would advise against `cd` into the latest dire and simply use the same scheme to get the latest file in that folder by appending `latest_folder/` with your command substitution.

Once you have the `latest_file`, you can simply use *parameter expansion with substring removal* to isolate the leading 3-digit number (e.g. `filenum="${latest_file%%.*}"`). After than you can make your decision on whether a new directory is required based on `filenum`.

If you do need to create a new directory, then use can use `printf -v` to take advantage of the field-width modifier and `'0'` padding to format your `new_folder` names a `002` by simply adding `1` to the `latest_folder` number, e.g. `printf -v new_folder "%03d" $((latest_folder + 1))` note: that is after removing the leading-zeros from `latest_folder` to prevent interpretation as Octal constants when adding `1` to get the `new_folder` number, e.g. `$((latest_folder + 1))`.

Putting it altogether, you should be able to do something similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash

limit=999

latest_folder="$(ls -td */ | head -n 1)"                ## latest folder
latest_folder="${latest_folder:0:(-1)}"                 ## remove / at end
latest_file="$(ls -t "$latest_folder/" | head -n 1)"    ## latest file
filenum="${latest_file%%.*}"                            ## isolate ###
if ((filenum == limit)); then                           ## if ### = 999
    n=0
    while [ "${latest_folder:n:1}" = '0' ]; do          ## remove zeros
        latest_folder="${latest_folder:$((n+1))}"
        ((n++))
    done
    printf -v new_folder "%03d" $((latest_folder + 1))  ## new folder name
    mkdir -p new_folder                                 ## create new folder
fi
```

**note:** you should generally use `find` and `sort` to get the list of directories and filenames (using `-maxdepth` and `-type` to control the depth and type of file/dir searched for)

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I'm getting an error within the printf line: 01/: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/")

Comment: Ok let me look.. Anything is possible. Add `printf "lastest_folder after 0 removal: %s\n" "$latest_folder" This needs to be directly after the `done` statement

Comment: its printing out: '01/'